# Which is right? "Ambitious students are more likely to succeed than are those with little ambition / than those with little ambition

Tags: grammar, comparatives

Which is right? "Ambitious students are more likely to succeed than are those with little ambition" or "Ambitious students are more likely to succeed than those with little ambition"

Answer (score -2):

"those" is the plural of "that". Since your question involves a person, I believe you would be better to phrase the question with "they" in the plural and "he/she" in the singular. So then your question would look like this: "Which is right? "Ambitious students are more likely to succeed than are they with little ambition" or "Ambitious students are more likely to succeed than they with little ambition"". With this in mind let us convert your question into the singular to find your answer: "An ambitious student is more likely to succeed than (is) he with little ambition" OR "An ambitious student is more likely to succeed than he with little ambition" By converting your sentence to the singular it is easier to see which is right and wrong. With the second being correct I would say that the correct way to make your statement would be "Ambitious students are more likely to succeed than (they/those) with little ambition.". Again however, I would use "they" instead of "those".